# "External component has thrown an exception." Exception when calling WicRenderTarget

Tags: c#, sharpdx, unresolved-external

The code being called:

```
try
{
    renderBitmap = new WicRenderTarget(DXManager.Factory, host.bmp, new RenderTargetProperties());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Exists entirely so that we can set a break point to catch this on the Exception.
    throw ex;
}
```

*host.bmp* is a SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap. We are occasionally getting the abovementioned "External component has thrown an exception." exception with an error code of "-2147467259" (which maps to 0x80004005 or "Unspecified error") and the following stack trace:

```
at SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory.CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget(Bitmap target, RenderTargetProperties& renderTargetProperties, RenderTarget renderTarget)
   at SharpDX.Direct2D1.WicRenderTarget..ctor(Factory factory, Bitmap wicBitmap, RenderTargetProperties renderTargetProperties)
   at MyCompany.Framework.DirectX.DXRenderableImage.Surface..ctor(DXRenderableImage Target, PointF NewOrigin, Color BackgroundColor) in Source ....\\Framework\\DirectX\\DXImageSurface.cs:line 150
```

The code for the DXRenderableImage.Surface constructor is the code mentioned at the top of the question, which essentially just invokes the WicRenderTarget constructor.

As far as I can tell, the factory is good. This exception happens when we're working with fairly complicated pages in rapid succession, generating preview thumbnails for saving the pages. Our threaded save logic should only have this invoked one at a time, so this should be gated. This might be linked to difficulty attaining a Render Lock (we've seen that in a different exception under similar circumstance).

I'm just baffled at how to go about debugging this. The exception does not have any supporting information and otherwise everything seems to be in order. Does anyone either have an answer for me, or a good way to figure it out?

Comment: Does the exception have inner exception? What message the inner exception has?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: No Inner exception.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but to re-throw exception, you should not use "throw ex" this will eat up your stack trace. it is better to use just "throw" that will retain your stack trace.

Comment: 0x80004005 error generally indicates access denied / locking situation. do you think the image you are loading (host.bmp) might be getting locked between two threads? have you checked if your method is thread safe?

Comment: @gurpreet
We do have some issues with locked files in other places. I was unaware that x80004005 was linked to that sort of a problem. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, I no longer have access to this source code, as it was from a prior job, so I may never truly know the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I am re-posting this as an answer instead of comment.

**Firstly**
0x80004005 error generally indicates access denied / locking situation. do you think the image you are loading (host.bmp) might be getting locked between two threads? have you checked if your method is thread safe? you should release any loaded images after reading them into memory.

**Secondly**
You are probably not getting inner exception because you are using "throw ex" to re-throw exception this will eat up your stack trace. it is better to use just "throw" that will retain your stack trace.

Comment: Yours is the better answer, although it still doesn't resolve how I can fix this.

Comment: what i could do to help is to review some code and see if i can find something to refactor and try. i don't know if you can share some code via git hub or something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disposing your objects when you are done using them? It could be a memory leak. You can either add a finally-block to your try/catch and call Dispose() in it

```
finally
{
    renderBitmap.Dispose();
}
```

or use a using

```
using (renderBitmap = new WicRenderTarget(DXManager.Factory, host.bmp, new RenderTargetProperties()))
{
    // do the stuff you want with the render-bitmap
}
```

Comment: :) One small problem with that... the renderBitmap needs to persist past the constructor. But yes, we do call Dispose on it when the class is disposed of.